# Visual Studio Directory in the Output

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, directory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDVjf.jpg

Hey guy's I'm new to coding and I've installed visual studio code 2019. I tried making a Hello World program but in the terminal it keeps on showing my directory before printing the line hello world. Does anyone know how I can get rid of it??

Answer (score 0):

You can add this: "console": "internalConsole",in launch.json file, the default setting is: "console": "integratedTerminal",. Then you can get the pure outputs. But I suggest you get used to the verbose outputs because that shows what exactly the vscode does.